# Flutter deep links not working from browser

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deep-linking

I made changes in Android manifes as suggested here:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

So, new metadata and config has been added to MainActivity:

```
<!-- Deep linking -->
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="flutterbooksample.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

As a result, when I use adb for testing as they said to do:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \
    -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \
    -d "http://flutterbooksample.com/book/1"
```

I am getting what I want:

[image]

But if I try to open url `http://flutterbooksample.com/book/1` directly in browser on my emulator, nothing happens, browser opens page and theres no prompt to open url in my app.

Do I need to do anything else to make it working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Short Answer

You can't call the deep link URL from the web browser's search bar. First, you need to create an HTML page. Then you can click the link. It will work.

#### More details

In my case, I created an HTML file with a deep link and send it to my email.

**HTML file**

```
<a href="myapp://test">Open my app</a>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:host="test"
        android:scheme="myapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: How to read the data I sent from my html file in my flutter app? thanks